# How to show the Scrollbar in a NestedScrollView Programatically.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

```
NestedScrollView nestedScrollView  = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.content);
nestedScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

`setVerticalScrollBarEnabled` is not working in above code.

Comment: is your scrollbar hiding after sometime?

Comment: no... scrollbar itself not showing

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways:

**from Java code:** `NesteadScrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);`

**from XML code:** `android:fadeScrollbars="true"`

Simple as that!

Comment: Wait I will updating my answer

Comment: @JohnRubanSingh add this line inside nesteadscrollview tag 

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: "layout_behavior" not working... I am not using coordinator layout. Share programmatic solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

After some research found workaround for this problem. In android sdk view level scroll invoked from xml attributes. Do the following steps.

**Step 1:** create a xml file with `android:scrollbars="vertical"` and place it inside xml folder(inside res create xml folder and place the file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

**Step 2:** In Java file, add the following code snippet

```
NestedScrollView nestedScrollView  = new NestedScrollView(getBaseContext(),getAttributeSet());

private AttributeSet getAttributeSet() {
        AttributeSet attr = null;
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.xml);
            try {
                parser.next();
                parser.nextTag();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            attr = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
            return attr;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return attr;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first in xml add attribute in: `android:scrollbars="vertical"` for NestedScrollView and then in java code:

```
mNestedScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
mNestedScrollView.setScrollBarFadeDuration(0);
```

if remove that: `android:scrollbars="vertical"` from xml then it does not work